# My alias parser works on the command line but not from a script

Tags: bash, alias

I'm trying to create a simple script that will dump all my aliases into a file that bash can load when it starts up, while making sure the alias of - to popd works properly:

`alias -p | sed 's/alias -=/alias -- -=/' > ~/.bash_aliases`

If I run that on the command line, it seems to work, but if I put it in a script and run that (with `#!/bin/bash` at the top and `chmod +x`), instead I get an empty file. Can someone tell me what bit of bash lore I'm missing?

If it matters, I'm using bash v4.2.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell script inherits the calling program's environment variables and such, but it does not inherit things like aliases and command history.

If all of your aliases are in a common location, like `~/.bashrc`, you could source that file into your script first:

```
. $HOME/.bashrc
```

Then you would have, in that shell script's execution context, all of the aliases defined in the `.bashrc` file.

If your aliases are defined all over the place, there is no easy way to consolidate them. You would have to write this "save all my aliases" as a function instead. You could put something like this in your `~/.bash_profile`, for example:

```
function dumpalias {
    alias -p | sed 's/alias -=/alias -- -=/' > ~/.bash_aliases
}
```

Then, after logging out and back in, you can say `dumpalias` to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise aliases were not inherited. It works perfectly as a function.

Comment: you don't need to log out and in, just `source` or `.` your .bash_profile

Comment: Of course you don't. I recommended that only because `.bash_profile` often contains things like `PATH` extensions that are best done once per session only.

Answer (score 0):

When you put it in a script and execute it, you're starting a new shell, which doesn't inherit the aliases from your current shell.  So, the script *is* saving the shell's aliases; there just aren't any aliases defined in the shell where those commands are executed.

You can [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) the script to execute it in the current shell:

```
. /path/to/script
```

Or, you could write it as a [shell function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html).